# std::map causing C2664 error when inserting

Tags: c++, dictionary, memory, allocation, allocator

I'm writing my own memory allocator to keep track of memory used in my app. I'm currently just testing it in a stand alone test bed.
The error i have so far is C2664 it's the first time I've encountered it using the std::map.

This is the map:

```
std::map<intptr_t*, MemBlock> mAllocatedMemory;
```

This is the the code to attemp to insert it:

```
std::pair<std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<void*, MemBlock, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void*const, MemBlock>>, false>>::iterator, bool> buffer = mAllocatedMemory.insert(std::make_pair(pmem->memAddress, pmem));
```

This is the memory block struct:

```
typedef struct nMemBlock {
public:
    bool isMemBlockFree;
    size_t memSize;
    size_t memMemorySize;
    intptr_t * memAddress;
    nMemBlock * memNext;

public:
    nMemBlock(void) {}
    ~nMemBlock(void) {
        delete memAddress; memAddress = nullptr;
        delete memNext; memNext = nullptr;
    }
} MemBlock;
```

Here is the memory allocator so far as i say i'm testing things never wrote one before:

```
class MemAllocator {
    // Methods
public:
    MemBlock * AllocateMemBlock(size_t size) {
        MemBlock * block = (MemBlock*)malloc(0);
        void * memAddress = (void*)malloc(0);
        void * allocateMem = (void*)malloc(MemBlockSize * size);
        if (allocateMem == (void*)-1) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        else {
            block->isMemBlockFree = false;
            block->memAddress = static_cast<intptr_t*>(memAddress) + MemBlockSize;
            block->memMemorySize = sizeof(MemBlock) * size;
            block->memNext = nullptr;
            block->memSize = size;
        }
        return block;
    }

    // Constructors
public:
    MemAllocator() {

    }
    ~MemAllocator() {

    }

    // Operators
public:

    // Members
private:

};
```

This is the class i'm using to the allocator:

```
class MemManager_Test : public MemAllocator
{
    // Methods
public:
    void AddMemoryBlock(size_t size) {
        MemBlock * pmem = AllocateMemBlock(size);

        if (pmem == nullptr) {
            // handle error
            return;
        }
    // this seems to be the line causing the problem, it's saying something about "no instance overloading"??
    std::pair<std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<void*, MemBlock, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void*const, MemBlock>>, false>>::iterator, bool> buffer = mAllocatedMemory.insert(std::make_pair(pmem->memAddress, pmem));
}

    // Constructors
public:
    MemManager_Test() {

    }
    ~MemManager_Test() {

    }

    // Operators
public:

    // Members
private:
    std::map<intptr_t*, MemBlock> mAllocatedMemory;
    size_t mSize;
};
```

**UPDATE**
It appears it cannot convert the first type of the pair or `intptr_t*` when constructing.

Compiler output is saying:

s-ct-main.cpp
z:\game engine(s)\serenity-engine\code\console-testbed\include\s-ct-mem-manager.h(163): error C2664: 'std::_Tree_iterator>> std::_Tree>::insert(std::_Tree_const_iterator>>,const std::pair &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair' to 'std::pair &&'
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::pair<__int64 *const ,MemBlock>,
              _Kty=intptr_t *,
              _Pr=std::less<__int64 *>,
              _Alloc=std::allocator>
          ]
          and
          [
              _Kty=intptr_t *,
              _Ty=MemBlock
          ]
  z:\game engine(s)\serenity-engine\code\console-testbed\include\s-ct-mem-manager.h(163): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'std::pair' to 'std::pair'
          with
          [
              _Kty=intptr_t *,
              _Ty=MemBlock
          ]
  z:\game engine(s)\serenity-engine\code\console-testbed\include\s-ct-mem-manager.h(163): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: I'm pretty sure your compiler prints a little more information than just `C2664`.

Comment: Why not `auto buffer = mAllocatedMemory.insert(std::make_pair(pmem->memAddress, pmem));`?

Comment: Here's some [info on C2664](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2664). The message is `'function' : cannot convert argument n from 'type1' to 'type2'`.

Comment: Please edit the complete error message into your question.

Comment: I have shown the compiler information. It's in an update to the original question above. It seems there is no operator to convert the type i'm using for the first element of the pair, i think *gulp*....

Comment: Am i right in thinking that it can't construct the pair due to the `intptr_t` type? I'll just write a custom array for storing it, saves time and brain power. But if anyone more knowledgeable than me works out how to fix it let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

The type of the object to which you are assigning the return value of `mAllocatedMemory.insert(std::make_pair(pmem->memAddress, pmem))` is incorrect.

If you are able to use C++11 or higher, use `auto` type specifier.

```
auto res = mAllocatedMemory.insert(std::make_pair(pmem->memAddress, pmem));
```

If you are using an earlier version of the language, you need to use the explicit type `std::pair<std::map<intptr_t*, MemBlock>::iterator, bool>`.

```
std::pair<std::map<intptr_t*, MemBlock>::iterator, bool> res = 
   mAllocatedMemory.insert(std::make_pair(pmem->memAddress, pmem));
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert for documentation on the return type of `std::map::insert`.

Comment: Hey, the type is correct. The hard typed type is faster than letting auto work it out at run time. The problem is it can't construct the pair as the first element `intprr_t*` is unable to be converted, i think there is just no conductor for that type :(

Comment: Type for auto is deduced at compile time, there is no runtime overhead, even it doesn't affect compile time as compiler has to deduced the type for error checking anyway

Comment: @AliceFluff, I am not sure why you think the type is correct. You are using `std::pair<std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<void*, MemBlock, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void*const, MemBlock>>, false>>::iterator, bool>` as type of the LHS. The return value if of type `std::pair<std::map<intptr_t*, MemBlock>::iterator, bool>`. Those are incompatible types.

Comment: @AliceFluff *The hard typed type is faster than letting auto work it out at run time.* -- I guess you're not aware what `auto` does.  It has nothing to do with figuring out types at runtime.  The compiler has full information of the type when compiling your code, thus the reason `auto` was introduced into the language.  It is a convenience for the programmer when *writing* their program -- if the compiler knows full well what the type is, have `auto` as a shortcut instead of having the programmer guess a monstrous type.

Comment: Ill investigate further and see if i can get my code to work, if anyone has anything positive to say about solve the problem of inserting in to the map that would be great. Also mousing over the `auto` word reveals that is the type resolve at compile time. Now i'm even more confused

Comment: I just tried them getting the same problem and currently i'm using c++ 11 but still tried them all. It is saying the problem is to do with instance overloading. Think i'm going to step away have a smoke see if refreshing my mind helps

Comment: It's because `MemBlock * pmem = AllocateMemBlock(size);` should be `MemBlock pmem = AllocateMemBlock(size);`. It works not thanks for the help :)